# does not enter debug point (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, eclipse

I have set up the environment in Eclipse for NodeJS, and I write several lines for learning. 
In "Code A" as follows , I set break point in line 4, but it does not stop at this line while running debug.
However, it does stop at line 4 in  "code B".
I am new to NodeJS, what is happening behind?

```
code A
1. var fs = require('fs');
2. var abc = 'name';
3. fs.readFile('./data.txt', function(err, data){
4.  var temp = abc;
5. }); 

code B
1. var fs = require('fs');
2. var abc = 'name';
3. fs.readFile('./data.txt', function(err, data){
4.  var temp = "name";
5. });
```

Comment: 1  var fs = require('fs');
2  var abc = 'name';
3  fs.readFile('./data.txt', function(err, data){
4 var temp = abc;
5  });

Comment: What you report sounds like an issue with something other than your code (like your debugging technique or something like that) because the value you assign to the `temp` variable has absolutely nothing to do with whether it will execute that line of code or not.  Do you understand that it will execute line 4 AFTER it executes line 6 (assuming there is something on line 6) because `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous?